# c# AssemblyInstaller service install blocking access to dll file

Tags: c#, dll, service, installation

I am installing a service using the following code.

```
string[] commandLineOptions = new string[0];
System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer = new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(path, commandLineOptions);
installer.UseNewContext = true;
installer.Install(null);
installer.Commit(null);
```

The installation performs well, however after installation, while trying to remove dll file included with service, it is impossible to do it because of denied access. The problem disappears after closing the aplication (service is still installed). How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Dispose()` on installer or wrap code with "using":

```
using (var installer = new AssemblyInstaller(path, commandLineOptions))
{
    installer.UseNewContext = true;
    installer.Install(null);
    installer.Commit(null);    
}
```

From AssemblyInstaller on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.assemblyinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

`Dispose()  Releases all resources used by the Component.(Inherited from Component.)`